# Three.Js cannot set position of object

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am trying to build a rocketship model by add different shapes to a large group and position them at specific axis.

When I try to enable

```
rocketCone.position.y = 15;
```

so that the top of the rocket ship is higher up, I'd get an error message saying

"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'y' of undefined"

Comment: Post the rest of your code as well.

Comment: Read - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Answer (score 0):

```
rocketCone.position.y = 15;
```

> "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'y' of undefined"

This can happen when position is not initialised with any value. Check position. Because of this, `position` evaluates to `undefined`, and you can't set properties on `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

is rocketCone a geometry?

Because a geometry doesn't have a position. You have to create a

```
rocketConeMesh = new THREE.Mesh(rocketCone,new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial())
```

then set the meshes position:

```
rocketConeMesh.position.y = 15;
```

Comment: It was a geometry, i tried adding a mesh and position the mesh but that didn't do anything for me.

Comment: Did you add the mesh to the scene?

scene.add( rocketConeMesh )